# What are the differences between different platforms in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders, version-differences

I have both the PC version, through Steam, and the PS3 version of Dungeon Defenders.

I have maxed out the level of my Squire on PS3, and was surprised to find that on the PC I could raise skill points to a base level of 100 on my Apprentice on the PC version (the PS3 version seems to cap the skill points at a base of 70).

What other differences exist between platforms? Are the level caps the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a large number of differences between the versions for PC, PS3, and Xbox. It all depends on when they release patches for the respective platforms. They made the change for stat points in a few patches (can't remember which one). But they made the point cap raised from 70 to 100, and then more recently from 100 to 120 as you've noticed.

They tend to upgrade the PC version a lot quicker and you will find the most up-to-date information in [this forum](http://forums.trendyent.com/forumdisplay.php?56-PC-Patch-Notes).

A comprehensive list for the differences between the two would be a very large post.

The current PC patch information can be found [here](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?30004-Current-Patch-7.13c).